# Can't read Json utf8 with Post request

Tags: java, post, encoding, utf-8, request

I know a lot of subjects were made for Utf8 encoding issues. I've explored it but I didn't find a working solution... I got a function to make a Post Request :

```
private void sendingPostRequest(String url, String postJsonData) throws Exception {

    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    // Setting basic post request
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json;charset=utf-8");

    // Send post request
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(postJsonData);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String output;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((output = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(output);
    }
    in.close();

    //printing result from response
    System.out.println(response.toString());
}
```

And here is an exemple of `postJsonData` :

```
"{"t":"ñ"}"
```

Despite the `con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json;charset=utf-8");` it cannot read the Json :

```
Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON document: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x22
```